# How to set a path to upload a file in hosting with PHP

Tags: php, web-hosting

I want to upload some files to webhosting, not sure where the files will be saved.

This is the code I'm using. See that I pretend to save them in /stage/ folder.

```
 <?php
if(isset($_FILES['documents'])){

foreach($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['documents']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['documents']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['documents']['type'][$key];  
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"staging/".time().$file_name);
}
}else{
echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='hola.php' method='POST'>";
 echo "File:<input name='documents[]' multiple='multiple' type='file'/><input type='submit' value='Upload'/>";

 echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Files not shown in webhosting folders. Where should I create /stage/ folder? Is there some kind of permission to set? how about big files, any limitation? Am I using the right / or it it \?

[webhosting tree path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J83n2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in foreach

```
// Upload file
$moved = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"staging/".time().$file_name);

if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["documents"]["error"];
}
```

It will give you one of the following error code values 1 to 8:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE = Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE = Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL = Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially
>   uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE = Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR = Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE = Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION = Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file
>   upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused
>   the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with
>   phpinfo() may help.

Comment: @GermanEstradaPacheco if that is Array then use `print_r($_FILES["documents"]["error"]);`